Entity Getting Updated Even though it is not in the Transaction context Using Modifying and Transactional Annotation in Spring boot
I am updating a table mapped to an entity ChildEntity using @Modifying, @Transaction and @Query Annotation in repo method as shown below
     @Transactional
      @Modifying
      @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "UPDATE child c set c.name=:#{#child.childName}," +
          " c.doj=:#{#child.childDoj} where c.id =:#{#child.childId}")
      int updateChildEntityUsingDtoThroughParentEntity(@Param(value = "child")ChildReqDto childReqDto);

Here ChildReqDto is not an entity, just used as parameter to update a table child.
The above method is called from a service which fetches another entity as shown below
    public Integer updateChildEntityUsingDtoThroughParentEntity(Integer id) {
        Optional<ParentEntity> parentEntityOptional = parentRepo.findById(id);
        if (parentEntityOptional.isPresent()) {
          ParentEntity parentEntity = parentEntityOptional.get();
          parentEntity.setParentName("parentUpdated");
          parentEntity.setParentDoj(LocalDate.parse("2000-04-02"));
          return updateChildUsingRequestDto();
        }
        return 0;
      }
    
      private Integer updateChildUsingRequestDto() {
        ChildReqDto childReqDto = new ChildReqDto();
        childReqDto.setChildId(1);
        childReqDto.setChildName("c");
        childReqDto.setChildDoj("2010-10-10");
        return childRepo.updateChildEntityUsingDtoThroughParentEntity(childReqDto);
      }

the method updateChildEntityUsingDtoThroughParentEntity is a method which is not annotated with @Transactional annotation nor the service class is annotated with the same.
But then also when repo method is executed it is updating parent entity even though it is not in transaction context.

Can someone pls look into this, I am stuck in one of the requirements. Many thanks in advance

Repo is an interface. The Spring team recommends that you annotate methods of concrete classes with the @Transactional annotation, rather than relying on annotated methods in interfaces. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/annotations.html
